# ng-model-option not working with checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I am using [checkbox list](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) directive in my `AngularJS` app. There are many filters in the page which are using same directive. I want two way binding to happen when I click on submit button on the bottom.

That means, the moment user is clicking on `checkboxes`, `angularjs` shouldn't update its model values. When user click on a button then only the model should update if there is any change.

I tried `ng-model-options` with simple checkbox and with the checkbox list directive. But nothing is working.

[Simple example of checkbox with ng-modeloption](http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/1120/)

```
<div ng-app="checkbox" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkbx" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"/>
 check me
 <br>{{chkbx}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code otherwise we won't able to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @varit05 check now

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/w2zgay7r/

Comment: @varit05 Thank you for the fiddle but the model value is still changing when checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: value below is not changing. is that you want, isn't?

Comment: No, I want model value should change only when user click's on submit button.

Comment: oops! that is weird. because ng-model is two way binding directive so it want to happen, I guess.

Comment: Yes but ng-model-option was the only option but its not working with checkboxes.

Comment: Check now : http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/t7kr8/1121/

Answer (score 0):

first create one function in angular when user is check in check box pass name of checkbox and set is value is 1

when user is submit button get only those checkbox value witch is 1.